# Logging out of application on tab close

Tags: javascript, shibboleth

I'm working with a Shibboleth single sign on application and I'm doing some research to find out how to successfully logout of the application if a tab is closed.  I've tried handling this event on the client side using .beforeunload to delete the coookies but that doesn't work. I'm assuming it's because the application is HttpOnly. I also tried running the logout function on tab close but that doesn't work either because the window isn't active long enough to end the sessions on the IDP and the SP.

The only other idea I have left is to have a window popup on tab close but I'd probably be introducing new issues to this.  How is it that banking websites like chase.com can force a user to re-login on tab close?

Comment: What you're looking for is called [session cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

Comment: @Amy "However, web browsers may use session restoring, which makes most session cookies permanent, as if the browser was never closed."

Comment: Have you *tried* it?

Comment: Shibboleth has a session cookie already in use within the application but that cookie isn't cleared on tab close. This is why I initially thought to manually clear it out on the client side code but it didn't work.

Comment: Other websites don't use Shibboleth so they have different session implementation.  Frankly there is no way to be sure to be logged out in Shibboleth.